# Django change ordering of model items by using method

Tags: python, django, django-admin

In admin.py I am trying to present the model with different ordering of items. I would like to create a method for the model that would return the items reordered when needed and pass it to the admin.

Basically, my problem is that I have categories which can have subcategories. I'd like to present these as an indented tree in the admin interface.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ...
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, 
                               related_name='category_child')
    ...
    def reordered(self):
        # Here will be the method that returns the items reordered
```

How do I tell Django to use the method and work with the returned item set which comes reordered?

Comment: You should explain how yo want your items ordered. By name?

Comment: No, I want to write my own method that returns the list of items. I will need to check if the items has a parent, if it is a child of a subparent etc. I need to group these as well. Basically it will return a category tree.

Answer (score 0):

try this in admin class

```
fieldsets = (
        ('', {
            'fields': (tuple returned from your function),
        }),)
```